# Remove double slash in gitlab address

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

I set up gitlab on my personal server and used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25809733/570336) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29181994/570336) (along with some input from [this](http://ryansechrest.com/2015/08/use-apache-instead-of-built-in-nginx-in-gitlab-ce/) to make it work with my apache installation. Everything works fine, when I go to gitlab.example.com, I see the gitlab UI, can create accounts and so on. However, when I inspected the URI I get forwarded to, it is

`https://gitlab.example.com//users/sign_in` (note the two slashes after the domain). This is not really a problem, but I would like to know why this is and how I can fix this - especially since it works just as fine when I remove one of the slashes from the address. (So `https://gitlab.example.com/users/sign_in` is exactly the same).

In fact, I get forwarded twice:

- `GET https://gitlab.example.com` => `301 Moved Permanently` with `Location:https://gitlab.example.com/`
- `GET https://gitlab.example.com/` => `302 Found` with `Location:https://gitlab.example.com//users/sign_in`

This is my apache config file (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName gitlab.example.com
        ServerSignature Off

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPassMatch ^(/[^/]+\.(html|png|ico|css|txt))$ !
        ProxyPass /assets !

        <Location />
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all

                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
                ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.example.com
        </Location>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

        DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Is this a problem with gitlab? How can I work around it?

**Note:** I am absolutely unsure which module is causing the forwarding behavior, if you need any other config files, just let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want try appending a trailing slash <kbd>/</kbd> to the [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) target URL's  i.e. change

```
 ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

into

```
 ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

since you're applying those directives to a path that also terminates with a trailing slash <kbd>/</kbd> (or only a slash in this case: `<Location />`) as the manual warns:

> > If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.

Comment: Thanks, That worked like a charm - although I had to append the trailing slash to the other `ProxyPassReverse` directive, while the one you mentioned can stay unmodified (though it seems like it doesn't do harm to have the slash in both addresses): `ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080`, `ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.example.com/`